# php how to insert an element into array if is not null

Tags: php, arrays

I need to fill an array with a list of elements only if value is not null.
Is there a way to skip the array filling if value to be appended is null?

As example:

```
$list = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $modulo = ($i % 2);
    if ($modulo) $list[] = $i;
}
```

Is there a way to write the two statement in the loop into an unique one **without using $modulo variable**?

something like...

```
$list = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $list[] = ($i % 2);
}
```

The expected behavior is that $list array has to contain 1,3,5,7,9...

*This is not the real example as the ($i % 2) has to be replaced with a complex function applied on an array of 380k elements and may return something or null. And I want to exclude null values.*

Comment: You could just use the evaluation expression in your if statement.

Comment: Once you fix the parse errors, your code produces `1,3,5,7,9`, so I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about being cool like this:

```
$list = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   ($i%2) ? ($list[] = $i) : "";
}
```

However its a bit confusing how you describe it. Maybe you want:

```
$list = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   (!is_null($i%2)) ? ($list[] = $i) : "";
}
```

Or if you want the result of the function:

```
$list = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   (!is_null($a = ($i%2))) ? ($list[] = $a) : "";
}
```

It must be one of these ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**One:**

```
$list = array();
for (i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $modulo = ($i % 2);
    if (!is_null($modulo)){
       $list[] = $i;
   }
}
```

If the value is not a PHP `null` then you can add it to the `$list` array.

**Two:**

```
$list = array();
for (i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $list[] = $i;
}

$list = array_filter($list);
```

PHP [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove any `falsey` or `null` or `empty` values from the array, if this fits what possible values you have.

Comment: Also note that using `array_filter` will not give you sequential keys on the result array, so you might want to wrap it with `array_values` too in case the rest of the code depends on the array keys.